# what is mold situation in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

In the classroom, there is mold situation.

what does that mean? I don't understand. Is it about the classroom who is boring? Or the students who are old?

Comment: You should add how you came up with such interpretations. From a learning standpoint it's important.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mold  see definition 3.1 and 3.2 for *fungus*.

Answer (score 2):

There is something wrong  with that sentence. It's missing an article.

> In the classroom, there is **a** mold situation

Still, it's hard to understand. And it would be an unusual way to formulate it, but it could mean "a situation that's characterised by mold", i.e., the classroom is moldy. (These words are spelled as "mould" and "mouldy" in the UK).

But maybe I misunderstood something and that's not what what meant at all.

Comment: *Mold* is the American spelling of the word. *Mould* is the British spelling.

Comment: @JasonBassford I never knew that! Are you an American? How does my interpretation of "mold situation" seem to you?

Comment: I'm Canadian, so I'm familiar with both. I'm also used to hearing the phrase *mold situation* (or *mould situation*). Actually, *an X situation* is a kind of generic idiom. I would have answered it as you did.